# Is it good practice to code entire business form as single component (control)?

Tags: user-interface, winforms, component

Is it good practice to code entire business form as single component (control) and then proudly put it on window/form as the final step in development? Of course, this form can involve some other custom components/controls, e.g. business applications can use custom controls for selecting partners, stores, goods, because such tasks are done from multiple places in applications. But the main idea is to develop entire form as single component.

There are applications where such solution seems to be the only reasonable one. E.g. .NET WPF does not have MDI interface and any docking solution requires to build one large form. If business forms are single components then it is not hard to put them into this form (in different docking panels). Antother example is multitabl JavaScript SPA applications - it can be pretty easy to create new tabs dynamically and put dynamically forms-components on those tabs.

So - is it good practice to encode forms as .NET controls, as AngularJS directives and so on?

Comment: What would be the alternative approach?

Comment: Who knows, maybe there are alternatives what I don't know? I am coming from Delphi world and we have put everyting directly on forms, Delphi hase nice MDI interface capabilities, so there is not need to invest extra effort in putting everyting in components/controls.

Comment: WPF is highly composable.  You seem to consider MDI a requirement, but WPF doesn't need it to do the things you describe.  Ergo, I don't really understand what you are asking.